# XMLHttpRequest not firing/calling any [on] callback in react-native Android

Tags: android, react-native, callback, xmlhttprequest

`react-native` `v0.63.4` `android` `XMLHttpRequest` not calling any [on] `callback` after sending the request but if I check after in the request data, I find that ready state is `DONE` and the response status is `200 OK` and the data is there but none of the callbacks gets fired.

Here is the code I'm testing with.

```
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.onabort = () => {
    console.warn("ABORTED");
  };

  request.onerror = () => {
    console.warn("ERROR");
  };

  request.onloadstart = () => {
    console.warn("LOAD START");
  };

  request.onloadend = () => {
    console.warn("LOAD END");
  };

  request.ontimeout = () => {
    console.warn("TIMEOUT");
  };

  request.onload = () => {
    console.warn("LOAD");
  };

  request.onreadystatechange = (e) => {
    console.warn("STATE CHANGE", request.status);
    if (request.readyState !== 4) {
      return;
    }

    if (request.status === 200) {
      console.warn("success", request.responseText);
    } else {
      console.warn("error");
    }
  };

  request.open("GET", "https://api.github.com/", true);
  request.send();

  setTimeout(() => {
    console.warn(JSON.stringify(request, null, 2)); // this successfully log all the response data.
  }, 1000);
```

My `android/app/build.gradle` dependencies are.

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
    
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.4.0')
    
    def multidex_version = "2.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:$multidex_version"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}
```

My `android/build.gradle` is

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        RNNKotlinVersion = "1.3.72"
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        playServicesVersion = "17.0.0" // or find latest version
        androidMapsUtilsVersion = "2.2.0"
        androidXCore = "1.0.2"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.72"
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.2')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.5'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }

        google()
        jcenter() 
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

finally, my `AndroidManifest.xml` is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.myapp.app">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  
    <application
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:name=".MainApplication"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
      android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
      android:allowBackup="false"
      android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
      <!-- You will only need to add this meta-data tag, but make sure it's a child of application -->
     <meta-data
      android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
      android:value="mygooglekey"/>
     
     <meta-data
      android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
      android:value="@string/facebook_app_id"/>

      <!-- You will also only need to add this uses-library tag -->
      <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false"/>
      <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize|uiMode"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
      </activity>
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
      <activity android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity"
        android:configChanges=
                "keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name" />
      <activity
        android:name="com.facebook.CustomTabActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="@string/fb_login_protocol_scheme" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer? I was having trouble with React-Native's Fetch, and realized they implement fetch by wrapping XHR in promises. I tried XHR but then had the same trouble you have now. More odd is how the builds and fetch were working, but going to an earlier commit, even building it on a different machine does not fix it